# FlyWay No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, flyway

I try use FlyWay 6.0.Beta2 BaseJavaMigration and Mysql

```
@Slf4j
public class V1_7__ini_cf_template_2019_07_1 extends BaseJavaMigration {

  @Override
  public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
    log.info("111");
    try (Connection connection = context.getConnection()) {
      log.info("222");
      try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
          "insert into console.customers_settings (settings_customer_id, start_balance, max_balance_allowed, max_instance_allowed) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        log.info("333");
        statement.setLong(1, 3);
        statement.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(100));
        statement.setBigDecimal(3, new BigDecimal(200));
        statement.setBigDecimal(4, new BigDecimal(300));
        statement.executeUpdate();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason I get an error

*Unable to rollback transaction
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.*

And requests of a type. Work well

https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/java

```
public class V3__Anonymize extends BaseJavaMigration {
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        try (Statement select = context.getConnection().createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet rows = select.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM person ORDER BY id")) {
                while (rows.next()) {
                    int id = rows.getInt(1);
                    String anonymizedName = "Anonymous" + id;
                    log.info(anonymizedName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `Connection connection = context.getConnection()` inside the `try` -once you've done that, the connection will be closed before the Flyway engine has finished with it. With some extra logging, you can see that your exception happens *after* your migration has finished.

If you check the example here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations you'll see the statement is closed, but not the connection.